# assist with loop creating multiple js functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have an app i am building and i am having problems with it.  I think I may have found part of the problem.  Basically i need to have a loop which creates multiple instances of a js function.  and so it goes through a loop where the unique item is the image id...
i need to be able to call these functions specifically with a button; so i read up on this and you can store js functions in an array and call them distinctly...

so I attempted to do this, I do know that my loop is creating multiple instances of the function and storing them in my array; but I think it cannot tell them from one another; as it seems the button is calling the last function created even though it should not (but if they are all the same maybe it would do that)

with my "test case" i can see that it does create 5 seperate functions (i alerted the whole array just to see) - so i think i am either creating them wrong - or i am coding my buttons wrong to call them (or both)

i create the function array here:

```
<script>
var ajax_functions = new Array();
</script>
```

here is my button:

```
<button type="button" id="<?php echo $ajax_button_id; ?>" onclick="ajax_functions[<?php echo $image_id; ?>](<?php echo $image_id; ?>)" class="btn btn-default">MOVE</button>
```

here is where i create the functions (stripped out the guts of it):

```
foreach ($popup36_array as $key=>$value) {
$image_id=$key;

$input_name="g_input99_".$image_id;

?>
<script>

var the_img_id="<?php echo $image_id; ?>";

ajax_functions[the_img_id]= function(input_img_id) {

 } //end function
</script>
}//end loop
```

Anyway - my test case has 5 images; the first image id is 46 and the last is 50...

I suspected that maybe it could not tell the functions apart and so i added that variable "$input_name" - which is a string that ends with the image id...
so that should tell me which "function" is running...
and no matter which button i press it seems like that string always ends in 50...

(there are 5 images and a modal for each one to change the order); there is a form to change the order and my button at the end of the form that triggers the js function

so there are 5 modals created in the loop and 5 forms with 5 buttons...

I just dont think my button can tell the difference between the functions...

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks so much,  Gerard

Comment: from a scale from 1 to 100 how go are you in php and javascript?

Comment: i am at least a 7 in php but at best a 5 in js - maybe less - but i continue to learn...

Comment: what modals do you use?

Comment: you want to create 5 different function,why?

Comment: is the button provided in the modal form?

Comment: Poor methodology. It's okay to get data with PHP before output to HTML, for your initial page load, but you usually use PHP to `echo json_encode($assocArray);`  for use in a JavaScript AJAX success function. One function in JavaScript could probably handle the entire thing if you understand the keyword `this`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not call javascript functions stored in an array.

You need to store them in Object literals like :

```
var funcs = {
    func1: function () {
    },
    func2: function () {
    }
}
```

So you will need to change the logic inside your loop.

And then when you wish to call a function from this object, you can do so like funcs.func1()

Comment: hmm - thanks for that - i am thinking i could "count" the images that will be on the page; and as long as the keys can be a string from the loop (like ("func" + the_image_id) and so i can code it like what you have - just the keys will be a variable; but i just need to make sure on the "last one" it does not put a comma at the end ...does that sound like it would work?

Comment: I believe that should work perfectly.
You would have an object with func1, func2, func3 and so on and you can map the same to the image specific button.

Comment: thanks so much; have to head to bed but will certainly be trying that tomorrow and let ya know...

Comment: Not true, you can call JavaScript functions stored in an Array, so long as they are not already called, or they return a function that has not been called. Note: `()` calls the function. You can just put the function name or an Anonymous function in an Array.

Comment: _"you can not call javascript functions stored in an array"_?

Comment: Again, storing an anonymous function would definitely not solve the OP problem thus my approach of using an object literal...